# tmux key bindings don't work the same on mac vs linux

Tags: tmux

I have the following in my Tmux.conf:

```
   30 # switch panes using Alt-arrow without prefix
   31 bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
   32 bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
   33 bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
   34 bind -n M-Down select-pane -D
```

On my mac, this seems to bind to the "option" key, and all four arrows work. However, on Arch Linux, this does not seem to bind to the option key. I was able to get `C-Left` etc to work on Linux, which seems to bind to the "control" key.

How can I bind to the option key on linux?